# Take first 10 Characters from <p></p> and storing in variable to send at the end of a url

Tags: javascript, parameters, substring

Here's my current code, I'm currently stuck as I'm a JS noob.

I'm currently developing something to get info from a qr code. The info from the qr code is 10 characters long and gets placed in the paragraph tag. I want to take the 10 characters and add onto the end of a certain URL I have, so it can go to a certain profile. Hope that clears some stuff up. New to this website sorry! –

```
<p id="info">
            </p>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var text = document.getElementById("info").innerHTML;
        var res = str.substring(0, 10);
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = res;
    }
</script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">check</button>
```

This is as far as I have gotten.. Any help would be much appreciated. I'm sure it can't be too difficult, just too difficult for me.

Comment: what do you mean by 'send at the end of a url' ? You want to redirect to a new page?

Comment: just a error : var res = text.substring(0, 10);

Comment: Open your error console and read the error given. This is the first step in debugging.

Comment: I'm currently developing something to get info from a qr code. The info from the qr code is 10 characters long and gets placed in the paragraph tag. I want to take the 10 characters and add onto the end of a certain URL I have, so it can go to a certain profile. Hope that clears some stuff up. New to this website sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, I believe you've got a typo, edit as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
    var el = document.getElementById("info"),
        text = el.innerHTML,
        res = text.substring(0, 9);

    el.innerHTML = res;

    //use res here for whatever purpose you need it.
    var url = "http://myHostName.com/myPage/?res=" + res;
    window.location = url;
}
```

You where doing a substring on a var named str that was never initialized as per your code. I've also improved your var declarations to avoid selecting the element twice. Hope this helps.

Comment: Would I add the url im using between the quotes?

Comment: yes, and remember to add the query param as well: `?res=` and then concatenate it with `+ res;`

Comment: so like var url = "https://this_is_my_url.com/page?res=" + res;  Idk if i can give out the URL yet, sorry for  being difficult :(

Comment: @taxicala why have you defined a variable and then called the window.location its a waste of time and 2 lines of code when it can be used as 1? any reason why

Comment: Thank you guys. I think I got it. I learned a lot in the process as well. I would vote you all up or whatever commendation is appropriate but it says I need 15 credits or something :(

Comment: Because he might want to do something before with the var idk really he could just use window.location directly with the string. It's just a rough example no need to be extremely picky about this.

Comment: i know but over use of code like that is doubling that one process.. sorry i get very picky about code lol @taxicala

Comment: var url = "https://didntwork.com?res=" + res; gave me a 404 server error :c Ill have to check back monday at what that could be

Comment: I am picky as well when coding something for production  but as I said this is just a rough example

Comment: @AaronStone that sounds like the url you are redirecting does not exist on your project.

Comment: what is your live url? @AaronStone

Answer (score 0):

you nearly had it but it was a syntax error on `str.substring` as you need to pass in the value you want to break down in this case `text` as `str` was not defined. please note if you want the first 10 characters you want to do `text.substring(0, 9);` as the variable starts as 0 based. Full code below

```
function myFunction() {
    var text = document.getElementById("info").innerHTML;
    var res = text.substring(0, 9);
    window.location = "www.whateveryourwebpage.com?text=" + res;
}
```